# How to do the parse step in ANTL4

Tags: java, kotlin, antlr, antlr4

I've generated the relevant Java classes given a lexer.g4 and parser.g4 file

[image]

I've written a visitor, but in order to use the Visitor, i need an actual parse tree, how do i get the parse tree from the parser?

In other online examples, there's mention of `parser.parse()` but that doesn't compile under ANTLR4

```
class Visitor : PostgreSQLParserBaseVisitor<Unit>() {

    override fun visitSelect_stmt(ctx: PostgreSQLParser.Select_stmtContext?) {
        println(ctx?.text)
        super.visitSelect_stmt(ctx)
    }

}

object Scratch {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val sql = """
            SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 1
        """.trimIndent()

        val lexer = PostgreSQLLexer(CharStreams.fromString(sql))
        val parser = PostgreSQLParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))
        val parseTree: ParseTree = parser.??? <<<

        Visitor().visit(parseTree)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse()` method corresponds to a parser rule called `parse`. If [this](https://github.com/tshprecher/antlr_psql/blob/master/antlr4/PostgreSQLParser.g4) is the PostgreSQL grammar you're using, you'll probably want to use the `root()` method belonging to the entry rule of the grammar:

```
root
    : stmt ((SEMI stmt)+ SEMI)? EOF
    ;
```